# What was the oak branch of Dodona (within Argo) called?

Tags: greek, argonauts

This [link](http://www.miscellanies.org/mythology/mag2/heroes/argo.html) makes it seems like it was referred to as "Koraki" but it seems like fan-fiction and I cannot validate using any of the accessible references.

Answer (score 5):

Koraki in Greek is κοράκι meaning crow or raven.

Noticing other articles on that site the authors name is on top just like the "koraki". It's probably a made up name used to make the story more interesting. I certainly found no other references to Koraki in the ancients texts applicable to this story.

Answer (score 3):

### Argo

The idea of *Argo* containing a branch of the Dodona Oak comes from the Hellenistic epic *[Argonautica](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/830/830-h/830-h.htm)* by Appolonius of Rhodes.  In Book 1, the Argonauts are getting in the ship preparing to leave Pagasae in Magnesia, when an astonishing thing happened:

> And a strange cry did the harbour of Pagasae utter, yea and **Pelian Argo herself***, urging them to set forth. For in her a beam divine had been laid which Athena had brought from an oak of Dodona and fitted in the middle of the stem.

The Dodona Oak branch was a magical ingredient that gave the ship itself a voice. Although the fanfiction you link to mentions a "plank", notice that *Argonautica* says the Dodona branch was "fitted in the middle of the stem" This refers to a ship's bowsprit, which is where more recent wooden ships would mount the figurehead. In an ancient ship with eyes painted on, the bowsprit would resemble the bridge of the nose when the ship was viewed head on.